# How do I get a dump of every Twilio number I currently own?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

I'm trying to find a way to see every number I've bought on Twilio and still control - either from the console or with an api call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can see all [your Twilio numbers in the console here](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming).

You can also get the numbers using the REST API. You'll need the [Incoming Phone Numbers list resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers). You can do this with Python and the [Twilio Python helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python), for example, like this:

```
from twilio.rest import Client

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "your_account_sid"
auth_token = "your_auth_token"
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

# A list of number objects with the properties described above
for number in client.incoming_phone_numbers.stream():
    print(number.phone_number)
```

Let me know if this helps at all.